# Notificación en Android

Tags: android

Quisiera saber si puedo mostrar una notificación  en una aplicación Android  cada vez que se inserte un nuevo registro en la base de datos que esta ligada.

La base de datos es MySQL.

Comment: La respuesta es que si se puede, tienes que que usar sockets y cada vez que envíes un registro a la base de datos aparte también enviar un evento al cliente android que tiene que estar esperando dicho evento.

Comment: ¿El registro se añade desde la app Android, desde la web o desde qué otro punto? Lo digo porque dependiendo de desde donde se inserte el dato, se puede realizar de una u otra forma. Damos un poco más de detalles. Gracias. :)

Comment: El registro se añade desde una aplicación  de  escritorio, desarrollada en Visual FoxPro .

Comment: Gracias!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 5):

En base a tu pregunta pense inicialmente que solo querías mostrar una notificación cuando insertabas un nuevo registro dentro de una BD de una aplicación móvil, por lo cual generarías una [notificación](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html)

Si agregas el registro desde una aplicación desktop y quieres enviar una notificacion a un móvil, necesariamente serían PushNotifications atraves de GCM.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Lo recomendable es ahora implementar FCM ya que GCM tendera a ser obsoleto.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

---

Si deseas solo mostrar una notificación normal cuando se inserta un nuevo registro, puedes realizarlo identificando la correcta inserción del registro y creando la [notificación](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html) ó haciendo uso de un Trigger, posteriormente generas la notificación:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/faqs-triggers.html#qandaitem-B-5-1-10

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Se puede hacer esto si la aplicación android no se conecta a internet?

Comment: Me refiero a si se puede usar firebase para enviar notificaciones a un dispositivo que se encuentra conectado de manera local es decir no se conecta a Internet, la notificación se le enviaría si no ha utilizado la app en x tiempo

Comment: Se pude realizar pero mediante una notificación normal , no utilizando FCM, actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: Pero yo quiero enviarle una notificación al dispositivo por motivo que no ha utilizado la app en x tiempo y para las notificaciones normales se debe ejecutar la app para poder enviar notificaciones o no es necesario?

Comment: Si tu la vas a enviar a un dispositivo, en realidad quien la envía es un servidor google, por lo tanto si se necesita conexión a internet.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que debes de hacer es lo siguiente:

1. Agregar GCM a tu proyecto android, la guía [aquí](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start)
2. Desde la aplicación en Visual FoxPro hacer un POST a google, la guía [aquí](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http)

Con este método la notificación llegará a todos los dispositivos que tengan la aplicación, si quisieras enviar a un es específico, debes de enviar (de alguna manera) el identificador del dispositivo a la aplicación de escritorio.